# how to show limited characters if clicked on more link then show full details?

Tags: angularjs

I am creating job portal using angular. I have job post listing. I want to limit job description character. And if clicked on "more" link it should show full description. I tried when I clicked on more link then it shows all job post description.
    view:

```
<div>
  <p class="para" ><b>Job Description</b> - {{job_list.job_description  | limitTo : limit}}
     <a href ng-click="change_length_value(job_post_listing.jobdata,$index)"> ...More
      </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

controller.js

```
$scope.limit = 3;
$scope.moreShown = false;
$scope.change_length_value = function(arr,ind){      
    $scope.limit=arr[ind].job_description.length;
    $scope.moreShown = true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using js slice

```
jobDescription.slice(0, $scope.limit);
```

this will limit the text to number o characters needed

you can also use css by doing the div containing job description to have

```
width: 200px;// for example
overflow: hidden ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the refactored code.

view

```
 <div>
  <p class="para" ><b>Job Description</b> - {{job_list.job_description  | limitTo : job_list.show_full_desc ? job_list.job_description.length : limit}}
     <a href ng-click="change_length_value(job_list)"> ...More
      </a>
   </p>
 </div>
```

controller.js

```
    $scope.limit = 3;
    $scope.change_length_value = function(joblist){      
        //Toggle show_full_desc;
        joblist.show_full_desc = !joblist.show_full_desc;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, is that you modify common `$scope.limit`, which affects on all rows. Instead you should change *"local"* `limit` - only for clicked row.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.limit = 3;
  $scope.job_lists = [
    { job_description: '123456789012345678901234567890' },
    { job_description: '123456789012345678901234567890' },
    { job_description: '123456789012345678901234567890' }
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <div ng-repeat='job in job_lists'>
    <p>{{job.job_description | limitTo : limit}}</p>
    <a href='#' ng-click='limit = job.job_description.length'> ...More</a>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```